# How do you scale postgres to billions of rows for this schema?

Tags: postgresql

Consider this scenario.

You're a link shortening service, and you have two tables:

- Links
- Clicks - predominantly append only, but will need a full scan to produce aggregates, which should be (but probably won't be) quick.

`Links` is millions of rows, `Clicks` is **billions** of rows.

Should you split these onto separate hardware? What's the right approach to getting the most out of postgres for this sort of problem?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use postgresql? Its look like not best choice for "billions of rows". Prefer to use key-value database: redis, cassandra etc.

Comment: I guess it's not mandatory, but it begs the follow-up question, how do you then query/aggregate the data in that scenario?

Comment: i think: sharding and/or partition. Data structure hightly depends on which particular queries do you want. Only quick find_by_link or some report ? Main problem: find key for sharding or partition

Comment: First of all, need to know: what aggregation do you need? Aggregation is main problem for billions data

Comment: there is key value pair support for postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html

Comment: At the most basic level, count of clicks, grouped by day.

Comment: Maybe [PipelineDB](https://www.pipelinedb.com/) is an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to partitioning, I suggest pre-aggregating the data. If you never need the individual data, but only aggregates per day, then perform the aggregation and materialize it in another table after each day is over. That will reduce the amount considerably and make the data manageable.

Answer (score 1):

With partitioning, it should be scalable enough. Partition links on hash of the shortened link (the key used for retrieval). Depending on your aggregation and reporting needs, you might partition clicks by date (maybe one partition per day?). When you create a new partition, the old one can be summed and moved to history (or removed, if the summed data is enough for your needs.